# Cannot Create or Read files from storage when App launched from another

Tags: android, uri, intentfilter

I'm opening my **Application A** from **Application B** using below code.

```
public void openApp(Context context, String appName, String packageName) {
        if (isAppInstalled(context, packageName)) {
            if (isAppEnabled(context, packageName)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(AppConst.ACTION_CONSTANT);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Init from Communicator");
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.install_latest_app, appName), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.app_not_enabled, appName), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.app_not_installed, appName), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is, i'm getting the URI of selected Image file from Gallery using

```
private void openGallery() {
        Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        getIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        pickIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Image");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{pickIntent});

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
    }
```

The resultant URI I'm passing to server using `ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback` by setting

```
mUMA.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{capturedImageUri});
```

This all is working fine when i'm opening the application, but failing when opening from **Application B**.

Do i need to set any extra permission settings when opening from **Application B** ?